# Laravel 4: validate checkbox at least one

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I need to validate checkbox array:

```
<input name="cats[]" type="checkbox" value="1"> sport
<input name="cats[]" type="checkbox" value="2"> music
<input name="cats[]" type="checkbox" value="3"> business
```

I found "array" validation in documentation:

```
Validator::make( 
    [ 'cats' => Input::get('cats') ],
    [ 'cats' => 'array' ]
);
```

Is there any built-in way to check if at least one item checked? Also, how to check if values submitted match a given list?

Comment: Did you see this related question? [Laravel 3 - How to validate checkbox array, for at least 1 checked?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16326693/)

Comment: can't use this? foreach($cats as $key=>$value){ echo (is_numeric($value)) ? $key."th key is numeric" : $key."th key is not numeric"; }

Comment: I ask for built-in (in Laravel 4) solution

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use min:*value* to validate a numeric value and you can also use it to validate an array's size.

```
Validator::make( 
    [ 'cats' => Input::get('cats') ],
    [ 'cats' => 'min:1' ]
);
```

Examples:

```
$validator = Validator::make([
    'cats' => ['Boots', 'Mittens', 'Snowball']
    ], ['cats' => 'min: 1']);

$result = $validator->fails(); // returns false

$validator = Validator::make([
    'cats' => ['Boots', 'Mittens', 'Snowball']
    ], ['cats' => 'min: 2']);

$result = $validator->fails(); // returns false

$validator = Validator::make([
    'cats' => ['Boots', 'Mittens', 'Snowball']
    ], ['cats' => 'min: 4']);

$result = $validator->fails(); // returns true
```

Comment: no "min" validate only length of text, not length of array, (tested  not working)

Comment: where in Laravel API (you found that "min" can validate array size)? please provide link?

Comment: I have not seen it in the documentation. I didn't know this was possible until today. I looked at [Validator.php](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php) - and if you look at the getSize function, you will see that it does in fact validate arrays by their size.

Answer (score 9):

As of laravel 5 you can just add required rule

```
<input name="cats[]" type="checkbox" value="1"> sport
<input name="cats[]" type="checkbox" value="2"> music
<input name="cats[]" type="checkbox" value="3"> business

// Controller
$rules = $this->validate($request, array('cats'=>'required'));
// will do the work
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind touching your input data, you could do:

```
$data = Input::all();
$data['cats'] = Input::has('cats') ? implode(',',$data['cats']) : null;
$rules = [ 'cats' => 'required|in:foo,bar' ];
$validator = Validator::make($data, $rules);
```

Answer (score 2):

Bit late to this party but surely just making it "required" will suffice?

```
public function rules(){
    return [
        'checkboxarray' => 'required'
    ];
}
```